# Is it possible to renject decoder's output as input for decoder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a tensorflow model, using keras, particularly an autoencoder for anomaly detection. My input is a sequence of physical values.
I want to use as decoder's input (as usual) the encoder's output and also the reconstructed sequence of the previous iteration.
I tried using the layers.Concatenate() function; my idea is concatenating the encoder's output with the decoder's output which I initialized with a tensor of zeros for the first iteration.
This is how i buld the model:

```
encoder_input = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2]))
x = Dense(256, activation='tanh')(encoder_input)
x = Dropout(rate=0.2)(x)
x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(x)
encoder_output, state_h, state_c = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)(x)

encoder_state = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_output = tf.zeros([1,x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2]] , dtype = tf.float64)
decoder_in = Concatenate()([encoder_output, decoder_output])
decoder_input = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(decoder_in, initial_state=encoder_state)
x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(decoder_input)
x = Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')(x)
decoder_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(x_train.shape[2]))(x)

model = Model(encoder_input, decoder_output, name="autoencoder")
```

When i try to fit the model i get a complex error that I can't understand.
I didn't found anything like that on the internet, is it possible to save and reinject the reconstructed sequence to the decoder?
Which is the best practice to do something like that?

Comment: u could create a double decoder... in this way, the output of one could be used as input of the other... u'll have a network with two outputs (the same for both decoder) and two losses to minimize

Comment: @MarcoCerliani thank you for your comment, I'm trying to understand better... which would be the inputs of the decoders? Would they have the same structure?

Comment: for the first decoder (encoder_output) for the second decoder (encoder_output and decoder_output)